# Charles Proxy capture tvOS 10.2?

Tags: apple-tv, charles-proxy, tvos10

Up until recently, I've been successful using Apple Configurator 2 to load a profile onto an Apple TV that had the IP address of the Mac running charles (and connected via usb), and the Charles.cer certificate.   This allowed me to capture Charles logs of apps running on the Apple TV.

I suspect the recent tvOS 10.2 release is the culprit, but this approach no longer works, and I'm unable to load profiles.

Anyone in StackOverflow-land been successful in capturing Charles logs in tvOS 10.2?

Comment: We have the same issue here. We click on "install" and nothing happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These type of profiles are now "Supervised devices" only. If you look at the device console, you'll see these lines:

```
Apple-TV profiled[146] <Notice>: Installation failed. Error: NSError:
Desc   : Profile Installation Failed
Sugg   : This profile can only be installed on a Supervised device.
```

**UPDATE** To make a device "supervised", you need to use Apple Configurator 2 version 2.4+. Please be aware that this is NOT an update to Apple Configurator 2 version 2.2, it's a separate download on the AppStore... You can now upload the profile that contains Global HTTP Proxy and Trusted Certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've been trying unsuccessfully to make the Apple TV a supervised device.  Will respond with instructions if I'm successful

Comment: Configuring with the latest 2.4+ Configurator and setting up both a Global HTTP Proxy and Trusted Cert still does not work for deciphering https connections via Charles on tvOS 10.2.

On iOS 10.3 in Setting -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings, you have to explicitly trust the installed Charles Proxy Custom Root cert now, but there's no equivalent way to trust the cert on tvOS 10.2 - this appears to be the root cause.

Comment: Updating the Mac OS to 10.12.4, and the Configurator to 2.4 did the trick for me.  In Keychain access I deleted the existing Charles cert.  After that was deleted, I exported a new .CER file from Charles, opened it in Keychain Access, and changed everything to <Always Trust> and saved.  I used this new .CER file when creating the profile which I loaded onto the Apple TV.  Thanks for the help legege!

Comment: @RichCraig are you able to get decrypted content for https? I followed your way and only get encrypted traffic for https. I'm on Mac OS 10.12.4, Configurator 2.4 and tvOS 10.2

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it my making my Apple TV "supervised". I followed this tutorial to have the Apple TV marked as supervised in Apple Configurator 2.4:  https://support.jamfnow.com/hc/en-us/articles/207704656-How-to-Supervise-an-iOS-Device-with-Apple-Configurator-2 (beware it will update the ATV to the newest tvOS version and erase everything on the ATV).

Comment: I can also confirm that after making the Apple TV "supervised" I can now see decrypted content for https in Charles again.

Answer (score 3):

According the Charles Proxy [page for setting up SSL Certificates](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/):

> As of tvOS 10.2 it is no longer possible to trust the Charles Root Certificate, so it is not possible to use SSL Proxying with tvOS 10.2. This appears to be because the Certificate Trust Settings menu is not available (see iOS devices above). A bug has been filed with Apple and we hope that this will be resolved in the future.

Comment: It has been quite some time for Apple to update this, but it appears to still have not been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In tvOS 11.4.1 I found Certificate Trust Settings in Settings > About

Comment: Are you sure? Don't see Certificate Trust Settings in Settings-General-About on tvOS 11.4.1. Maybe you meant iOS? Or tvOS 12? Please clarify.

Comment: Can't find it on tvOS 13.3.